# underscore.js: _.zip.apply example

Tags: javascript, underscore.js

I would like to see an example of `_.zip.apply` using underscore.js.

In the [underscore documentation](http://underscorejs.org/) is written:

> If you're working with a matrix of nested arrays, zip.apply can transpose the matrix in a similar fashion.

However, the documentation provides no example.

Answer (score 11):

It's your standard use of [`apply`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4zc42wh1%28v=vs.94%29.aspx):

```
_.zip.apply(null, [ ['foo','bar'], [0,1] ])
```

This would result in the following:

```
[['foo', 0], ['bar', 1]]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use also a 'non-external-library' method:

Create this function:

```
function transpose(arr) {
        return Object.keys(arr[0]).map(function (c) {
            return arr.map(function (r) {
                return r[c];
            });
        });
    }
```

and then:

var transposedArray = transpose(originalArray);